# error(MSB3073) in visual studio with unreal engine

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, ide, visual-studio-2015, unreal-engine4

I'm new using visual studio and unreal engine (but I learnt c++ previously). I'm in trouble right now. Let me explain :

I use Unreal engine 4.9.2 and visual studio 2013 update 4 (that has been installed) from UE.

When first open VS while creating a new project I have this error message : 
[image: first VS instance error]

but then VS opens normally.

Later, when I create a new actor in UE and that I try to build it adding just this line :

```
UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere)
```

I have 2 brand new error messages :

> Error        1        error code: OtherCompilationError (5)        E:\Documents\Unreal Projects\test4\Intermediate\ProjectFiles\Error        test4
>
> Error        2        error MSB3073: The command ""E:\programmes\unrealengine\Epic Games\4.9\Engine\Build\BatchFiles\Build.bat" test4Editor Win64 Development "E:\Documents\Unreal Projects\test4\test4.uproject" -rocket -waitmutex" exited with code -1.        C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.MakeFile.Targets        38        5        test4

What I tried to do to fix it : 
- remove and install again unreal engine and visual studio : **same issues.**

- install visual studio from another source and then install unreal engine (removing both and rebooting before, obviously) : **same issues.**
- Install Unreal Engine 4.10 => other issue, I'm not able to install Visual Studio 2015 (the installer packed with UE fails).
- Using UE 4.10 Install Visual studio 2015 from another source : **same Issues**
- Uninstall all and retry with UE4.9 and VS2013 : **same issues**

The complete source code of the header (the .cpp file has not been modified, it is still blank):

```
    // Fill out your copyright notice in the Description page of Project Settings.

#pragma once

#include "GameFramework/Actor.h"
#include "MyActor.generated.h"

UCLASS()
class TEST4_API AMyActor : public AActor
{
        GENERATED_BODY()
        UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere)

public:        
        // Sets default values for this actor's properties
        AMyActor();

        // Called when the game starts or when spawned
        virtual void BeginPlay() override;

        // Called every frame
        virtual void Tick( float DeltaSeconds ) override;

};
```

Honestly I learnt at school how to program using makefiles and linux but with an IDE, I am a total beginner. I hope someone will be able to help me. Thanks in advance.

PS : I apologize if I made grammar mistakes but english is not my native language.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
#pragma once

#include "GameFramework/Actor.h"
#include "MyActor.generated.h"

UCLASS()
class TEST4_API AMyActor : public AActor
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public:        
    // Sets default values for this actor's properties
    AMyActor();

    // Called when the game starts or when spawned
    virtual void BeginPlay() override;

    // Called every frame
    virtual void Tick( float DeltaSeconds ) override;

};
```

I think your problem is not immediately following UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere) with a variable. Standard syntax of UPROPERTY is:
     `UPROPERTY([specifier, specifier, ...], [meta=(key=value, key=value, ...)])
 Type VariableName;`

For more info: https://wiki.unrealengine.com/UPROPERTY